# Get Duplicate values when creating a dictionary with list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, duplicates

I have two lists as follows:

```
list1 = [0, 0, 1]
list2 = [0, 1, 2]
```

I zip them using:

```
zipped_list = zip(list1,list2)
```

The result is `zipped_list = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)]`
Now, I want to create a dictionary using list comprehension as follows:

```
d = {k:v for k, v in zipped_list}
```

The result is `d={0: 1, 1: 2}`

That is for the `key = 0` in `zipped_list`, the dictionary contains only the last occurrence of key, value pair.

The question is: how can I get all occurrences of key, value pairs for duplicate keys and not only the last one?

In the particular example, I would like to get

```
d={0: 0, 0: 1, 1: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible because you cannot have dicts with duplicate keys.

You can instead try to have a `list` of all values under the same key.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> zipped_list = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> for k,v in zipped_list:
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 1], 1: [2]})
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I achieve this with any other hashable data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same approach @Ashish is using but without any external modules (imports)

```
list1 = [0, 0, 1]
list2 = [0, 1, 2]

zipped = zip(list1, list2)

d = {}
for items in zipped:
    res = d.setdefault(items[0], [])
    res.append(items[1])

print(d)  # prints: {0: [0, 1], 1: [2]}
```

And yes, this can be achieved with any other hashable data structure if it is the *keys* you mean. `list1` could have been `list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b']` for example.

If you find `setdefault` too *fancy* take a look at its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).